# Where to aim after hooking with Roadhog?

Tags: overwatch

I've noticed that sometimes I'm one-shotting Soldier 76 and sometimes I'm not. The same goes with Reaper.

I'm worried that it may be because of where I aim.

Comment: The answers below are good. When I started playing Roadhog, I was having similar problems. After playing around with him a bit, I found that *speed* is just as important as aiming properly. When you hook someone, they will do their damnedest to **not** make an easy target for you. You need to shoot as soon as possible, before they have an opportunity to react after getting out of the stun. Sometimes, this means getting slightly un-optimal aim with the shotgun, but that's better than an outright miss or a target that retreats backwards in the cone of your shot.

Comment: This is also why I'm pressing hard with my friends to not stress about the melee attack. Your mind should focus on the actual shot. Then, if the enemy is still standing, you should melee. The melee range is something like 3.5 meters (Practice Range). It's just plain dumb.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Generally, you should aim where the most area possible is covered by the aim circle on the enemy character (most of the time the headshot bonus is neglectable). I tested all of it manually in a custom game with a friend.

Please note that melee attacking is a good way to squeeze an extra bit of damage. But just remember that the melee attack range is a bit ridiculous and that you should take more time focussing on the shotgun shot than the melee attack.

This would mean to aim (in offense to support order) :

---

### OFFENSE

**Genji :** You aim down on him since the hook brings him so close to you. Generally an easy one-shot.

**McCree :** The hips. As weird as this sounds.

**Pharah :** The hips once again. Note that Pharah has a weird pull distance, sometimes she'll be at the perfect distance, sometimes she won't.

**Reaper :** Around the stomach. His 250 HP are a pain, unless you get lucky or if someone shot him a little bit previously, he'll survive. Shoot fast or else he'll Wraith Form away.

**Soldier 76 :** the hips. This is the area where most of the bullets can get a hit.

**Sombra :** Hips, she's one of the harder characters to one shot, but it's still doable unlike Ana. Half a step foward should ensure you a kill if you follow it up with a melee.

**Tracer :** Same as genji. You aim down on her since the hook brings her so close to you. Generally an easy one-shot.

---

### DEFENSE

**Bastion :** 300HP is too much to one shot. Shooting him in the torso deals around 250 on average. You can have the leasure to take an extra step to deal a bit more damage. But it shouldn't exceed by a lot that 250 damage.

**Hanzo :** Hips.

**Junkrat :** High torso. Since he's postured like a litteral rat when you grab him, the high torso will get a part of the head and oneshot him.

**Mei :** You just can't one shot her and she'll go in Cryostasis right after. The hips seems to do the most damage.

**Torbjorn :** You aim down on him. Headshot being calculated, you can get through his whole health bar (and armor too).

**Widowmaker :** Hips. She seems a bit trickier than other characters because of her slim silhouette.

---

### TANKS

**D.Va :** The glass of her mech or her hips in the case of mechless. You can't one shot her mech. *(Duh)*

**Reinhardt :** His head. FINALLY. Reinhardt has such a huge necks those usual lost bullet will find place in there. You won't be able to one shot him but 2 good shots should deal with him.

**Roadhog :** Belly shot. (Random note, the first roadhog that hooks the other is usually the first one to die in a duel. Shoot him back after his hook and then Hook combo should take care of him.)

**Winston :** Head. See Reinhardt.

**Zarya :** Hips. But you have to shoot fast before she shields it. Should do around 220.

---

### SUPPORTS

**Ana :** You *can* one shot her. But it's very inconsistent. I won't risk myself to say where to shoot.

**Lucio :** Most satisfying to hook, easiest to kill. Shouldn't be a question where to shoot.

**Mercy :** Hips once again. Her hook distance is a bit inconsistent too.

**Symmetra :** Hips. Hook distance is a bit wonky too.

**Zenyatta :** Your aim circle just does the whole body of Zenyatta.

---

P.S. Roadhog's hook mechanics are really wonky by moments. These tests were done in a custom game with an opponent willing to get hooked but trying as much as possible to get out post hook. This could pretty much differ in a real game. Against some low mobility / no escape character you can take a second to take an extra step to deal a bit more damage.

P.P.S. I'd want to precise that these damage counts are calculated with someone trying as hard as he can to negate the damage of Roadhog. (Wraithform, Defense Matrix, Ice Block, etc.) So if you do take a step, jump or take too much time aiming, the damage might be completly negated or lower. Practice makes perfect !

Comment: I can't ever seem to hook -> shoot -> melee to kill Ana or Mercy, so I'll try this when I next play.

Comment: Oh. Thanks for the involontary heads up on melee. I'll add about it.

Comment: Thanks for the catch on the line breaks, I always mess that up...

Comment: Oh thanks to you ! I learned a lot on that one ! :p

Comment: If you just hooked an immobile hero, it's sometimes useful to take a short step forward and jump, shooting *down* at them towards their vulnerable spot. This ensures that some of the shotgun blast will count as a headshot, thus dealing more damage and potentially one-shotting the tankier champs (Reaper, Mei). However, this is a somewhat risky move, since the jump gives the enemy a handful of milliseconds more to react, which may be the difference between their death and their escape.

Comment: I find that, most of the time, the jump is irrelevant. A short step is enough and not even aiming for the head (depending on the character) is better because of the number of bullets that do land. But as you said, the only targets that matters are the one that can block completly your damage if you do so. At this point, it's more of a question of wether or not you are willing to sacrifice your whole damage for that chance.

Comment: You forgot to list solider 76 in offense.

Comment: Thank you. Added it. Same as McCree since they have the same silhouette

Comment: Is there any way that a character could quickly crouch after getting hooked, thereby negating the majority of the damage? I've seen clips of players even crouching underneath the hook, but is it possible to save yourself that way?

Comment: Good question. I'll try to test that... You are getting me interested now lol :P

Comment: Which fire mode do you use after hooking (or does it even matter at that close a range)?

Comment: Primary fire. The secondary only does considerable damage past the 10m line.

Comment: There are actually 2 distances Roadhog's hook will pull. Some heroes get pulled super close, and for those heroes they'll always be pulled to the close distance

Comment: Yes. I know that. But the "second" distance with the all the action of the battle (flying most of the time) gets screwed up a bit. Pharah and Mercy will sometimes get hooked and are too "Pharah"way to get one shotted. That's what I'm referencing.

Comment: When playing as D.Va, after roadhog hooks me and pulls me in, I pull up defense matrix, this often prevents any further damage if timed correctly, then I boost into his face!

Comment: When mechless, after he pulls me in I melee him and jump backwards and off to one side, sometimes I escape with my life, even though he fires his weapon he sometimes misses, this doesn't always work though

Comment: @D.Va There's currently no characters that can completly block or dodge Roadhog's first shotgun shot if he doesn't take his sweet time to shoot (stepping, jumping, etc). So yes, these techniques will work if he takes too long before shooting. I'll precise a bit.

Comment: @D.Va And if he's lagging like hell too. But yeah Defense Matrix after the damage burst might save your life. And mechless, if you miss your first shot on her... her profile is so slim, it's just plain dumb to aim.

Comment: Added Sombra to the list.